# Can someone [support] me in burninating this tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [support](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tag currently has 10 questions.

There is no tag description, and very little consistency in how it's used. By way of example, one question is about tech support, another one is how to handle an unsupportive boss, and one is about whether it's appropriate for a design engineer to be asked to do field support.

This tag has an unclear meaning and adds nothing to the questions that use it.

Can we burninate this?

Comment: There is a useful set of criteria on one of the main "burnination" meta posts, although the procedure described is massive overkill for our site: [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191)

Comment: Is there a reason why we need to burniate instead of just removing it from the 10 questions it’s on and letting it get deleted overnight?

Comment: @ColleenV That's what burnination is.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I associate burniation with more than 10 posts I guess. I’ve destroyed tags around that number of posts single-handedly when they have no description and there’s no consensus among the posts as to the meaning.

Comment: I'd agree with removing this tag from questions.  As stated, the usage of the tag is so ambiguous that it's unhelpful.

Comment: @Snow same here... based on what I read here I will proceed with the removal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the votes of this question, on the comments, and also on my judgment, I proceeded to remove such tags. It is now a pile of digital ash...

I also added relevant, related tags to the edited questions, in the case where it seemed fit.

[image]

Comment: And there's only ten questions, so bumping those with edits isn't likely to cause much in the way of disruption to the home page.  Some of those questions may even get better answers.